# How to inspect space issues on nodes in kubernate cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I have the micro cluster on GCloud running smallest imaginable Node.js application.

Eventhough app is going down all the time. Here is output of kubernate describe pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From               Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  1m (x2 over 1m)   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 2 node(s) were not ready, 2 node(s) were out of disk space.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  55s (x9 over 2m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were not ready, 1 node(s) were out of disk space, 2 Insufficient cpu.
```

I suspect maybe there is some garbage left from previous versions of an app. How can I check what causes problems and get rid of unnecessary processes and data?

Comment: Did you checked the [logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/#my-pod-is-crashing-or-otherwise-unhealthy) ? If any relevant information please added into the description.

Comment: You can SSH into the worker node and see what's taking up so much space. If you aren't rotating your docker logs, there's a chance that might be the culprit.